# Using a firebase storage image URL with CSS background property and url()

Tags: javascript, css, firebase, cordova, url

**UPDATE**

I wrapped the `forEach` in a promise to fix the intermediary error I was facing, but I am back to where I began. I was just trying to pass `self.data` as a parameter between functions but it didn't solve anything.

**UPDATE**

I think I am returning `self.data` incorrectly to `loadData` but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
this.loadData = async function() {
    var db = firebase.firestore();

    // Disable deprecated features
    db.settings({
      timestampsInSnapshots: true
    });

    var docsRef = db.collection("pools").doc(window.currentPoolId).collection("list").where("active", "==", true).orderBy("date").limit(8);

    var counter = 0;

    var result = await docsRef.get();

    console.log("querySnapshot result: "+result);
    result.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        self.data.push(doc.data());

        console.log("result.size: "+result.size);
        console.log("self.data.length: "+self.data.length);
        console.log("counter in loadData: "+counter);
        if(result.size - 1 == counter) {
            console.log("returning self data: "+JSON.stringify(self.data));
            return self.data;
        }

        counter++;
    });
}
```

The above function is called like this (I think it needs to be window.pool.loadData because of scope, instead of `this.loadData`):

var result = await window.pool.loadData();
console.log("result in populate else: "+result);

It outputs:

```
result in populate else: undefined
```

**UPDATE**

I'm pretty sure this is happening because the `pool` `global` hasn't been created yet when I am referencing `window.pool` - I think I had a problem using `this` inside the `pool` `global object` (as this code is inside the `pool` `global object`, but I am going to try it again.

After using `this.data[this.total_boxes].downloadURL`, I get the same results - it is printed correctly in the `console.log` message, but I get the same error saying it is `undefined`.

I'm not sure if there is a problem with my instantiation order or not.

---

I am trying to use the `downloadURL` I retrieved after uploading an image to `firebase storage`. I am trying to use it in the `url()` `css` function, and I am getting an error that says:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.pool.data[window.pool.total_boxes].downloadURL')
```

I am building for `iOS` right now with `cordova`. I use the `downloadURL` like this in my `javascript/css`:

```
var item_box = document.createElement("div");
item_box.style.flex = "1 0 50%";
item_box.style.display = "flex";
item_box.style.flexDirection = "column";
item_box.style.justifyContent = "flex-end";
item_box.style.borderBottom="2px solid #9a9a9a";

//THIS IS WHERE  I USE THE `downloadURL`, ALL OTHER CODE IS FUNCTIONAL
item_box.style.background = "no-repeat center/100% url("+window.pool.data[window.pool.total_boxes].downloadURL+")";

item_box.id = "item_box_"+this.total_boxes;
```

I have these three console messages before the above code:

```
console.log("window.pool.data: "+JSON.stringify(window.pool.data));
console.log("window.pool.total_boxes: "+window.pool.total_boxes);
console.log("window.pool.data[0].downloadURL: "+JSON.stringify(window.pool.data[window.pool.total_boxes].downloadURL));
```

They output:

```
[Log] window.pool.data: [{"active":true,"date":"1544583167324","description":"Comp","downloadURL":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pool-3f2de.appspot.com/o/share_images%2FpvxqKsDK3OelIMvWdnogYGmdqt33%2F1544583167324.jpg?alt=media&token=xxx","item":"Computer"}] (cordova.js, line 1732)
[Log] window.pool.total_boxes: 0 (cordova.js, line 1732)
[Log] window.pool.data[0].downloadURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pool-3f2de.appspot.com/o/share_images%2FpvxqKsDK3OelIMvWdnogYGmdqt33%2F1544583167324.jpg?alt=media&token=xxx" (cordova.js, line 1732)
```

I have this console message after the `item_box` element is instantiated (not yet added to the `DOM`):

```
console.log("item_box.style.background: "+item_box.style.background);
```

It outputs:

```
item_box.style.background: url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pool-3f2de.appspot.com/o/share_images%2FpvxqKsDK3OelIMvWdnogYGmdqt33%2F1544583167324.jpg?alt=media&token=xxx") center center / 100% no-repeat
```

So it appears that `window.pool.data[window.pool.total_boxes].downloadURL` is not undefined.

Why am I getting the `undefined is not an object` error when I can see that the object has the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a "duh" moment, but it was very tricky just because of how I had my log messages setup. It appeared that the value was undefined, but actually, it was only undefined on the next pass of the loop (the `item_box` element is created inside a loop) because the loop variable grew larger than the size of the data array.

At one point in my code I had:

```
for (var i = 1; (i * this.total_rows) < (9 * this.total_rows); i++) { ...
```

and needed:

```
for (var i = 1; (i * this.total_rows) < ((dataz.length + 1) * this.total_rows); i++) { ...
```

Notice how the `9` is a fixed number so it doesn't fluctuate with the size of the data being passed in (parameter representing `this.data` - `dataz`).